# Rails4.1, devise 3.2.4, rspec feature, How I get confirmation_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to write a feature-spec with the following steps:

```
visit "/users/sign_up"
fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'dan@dan.net'
fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'abc123'
fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', :with => 'abc123'
click_button "Sign up"
dan_confirmation_token = get_confirmation_token
visit "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{dan_confirmation_token}"
```

In previous versions of devise,
I could get dan_confirmation_token directly from:

```
User.find_by_email('dan@dan.net').confirmation_token
```

But devise is more secure now.

What is the API call I use to get dan_confirmation_token?

Comment: For fuller test coverage, consider using [email_spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) to assert the confirmation email is sent and to visit the link in the confirmation email. This avoids embedding confirmation token logic in the spec. For a working spec see https://github.com/eliotsykes/rspec-rails-examples/blob/32845ab93657a70500e8b08e28b65ae949f68a4f/spec/features/user_registers_spec.rb#L5-L36

Answer (score 1):

I got this working :

```
visit "/users/sign_up"
fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'dan@dan.net'
fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'abc123'
fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', :with => 'abc123'
click_button "Sign up"
visit "/"
usr = User.find_by_email "dan@dan.net"
raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(usr.class, :confirmation_token)
usr.confirmation_token = enc
usr.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
usr.save(validate: false)
visit "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{raw}"
```

I should note that usr.save(validate: false) will not work like I want unless I configure rspec to avoid using transactions:

vi spec/spec_helper.rb

set:
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

Since I'm using sqlite in my test-env, this is not a big deal.

At the end of each test-run I do this:

rm -f db/test.sqlite3

If I want to run my tests using Postgres, I will need to "clean my database" after each test-run.

To do that, I would depend on gem: 
https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the [Devise test suite](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/integration/confirmable_test.rb) for the Confirmable module to see how they do it. It appears you can call `raw_confirmation_token`; I don't know if that is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I actually saw that.  I tried this:  raw = user.raw_confirmation_token
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `raw_confirmation_token' for #<User:0x007f194c12f5e0>
(rdb:2) user.confirmation_token
"60d983082ff868c010c091021f2739351cfd0092073ddd2368f851b2b3cf6408"